# 'FORM_KEY is not defined' throws error when checkout process as guest or register

Tags: magento

I'm having an issue on a checkout page is not working when login as guest or register but works fine on normal login. It throws an error, "FORM_KEY is not defined
[Break On This Error] this.options.parameters.form_key = FORM_KEY; " when checkout process as guest or register.

Anyone got an idea? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if the checkout page is throwing an error and not letting you checkout it is due to a user modification of the checkout template files. I would back them up and then replace them with base or default files and see if you can checkout. I bet you can and thus you will need to add back in your changes one by one until you find out exactly where it breaks. Then you can fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this error. When I analysed then I found, this error was coming due to
**mage/adminhtml/loader.js** which is already being used in Admin Section.

Actually I have called this file in **header.phtml** due to some requirement.

when I did exclude this file, Error has gone away.

Hope it'll be helpful for someone :)